# how to use all cuda devices only for computation not for display in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, cuda

I am using nvidia geforce gtx 580 graphics card but  I am unable to debug the cuda C code using Nsight version of eclipse. (os: ubuntu 12.04).. Please suggest some solutions...

Comment: Do you have any other display device in that system besides the gtx 580?  If so, run the display on the other display adapter, and make sure X does not use the gtx 580.  [This document](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3029/~/using-cuda-and-x) may help.

Answer (score 1):

Run `init 3` as root and use cuda-gdb

Yes, this requires learning gdb.